# Parsing error: "," expected on conditional return

Tags: javascript

I really can get why, when I add a slice method to this function, i get a parsing error that needs a comma. Syntax looks correct to me. Any idea?

```
    const getObjectKeys = (object: any) => {
        Objeckt.keys(object).reduce((prevValue, value) => {
            if (value.startsWith("bo-")) {
                return { ...prevValue, value }
            } else {
                return { ...prevValue, value.slice(3) }
            }
        }, {})
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this `return { ...prevValue, value.slice(3) }`

Do this instead `return { ...prevValue, value: value.slice(3) }`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `return` keyword on outer function, and `value` key on last statement

```js
    const getObjectKeys = (object: any) => {
        return Object.keys(object).reduce((prevValue, value) => {
            if (value.startsWith("bo-")) {
                return { ...prevValue, value }
            } else {
                return { ...prevValue, value: value.slice(3) }
            }
        }, {})
    }
```